# Usage of 'it' in starting of paragraph

Tags: paragraphs

Can a paragraph start with a sentence containing 'it' even when the sentence does not introduce you to the noun or pronoun that 'it' is referring to?

Like the jumbled sentences..

A. For the moment, Tanzania is one of the east Africa's  few good-news stories.
B. Development economists use it as a measure.
C. That isn't saying much.
D. If Tanzania can haul itself out of poverty others can too.
E. The country remains wretchedly poor, inefficient, with little medical care in its remote areas, even in Dar es Salaam, the largest city.

Comment: What is the connection between your question and the jumble? Whick sentence would contain 'it'?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a paragraph (even an entire book) can begin with a sentence that contains a pronoun that hasn't yet been explained.  Dickens (A Tale of Two Cities) opened with

*"It was the best of times, it was the worst of times . . ."*

Journalists also might use the technique to begin a feature article as a tease or hook for the reader.  For example:

"It was good, but it could have been better."

Comment: +1 Seeing just the question title, I was reminded of "the best of times, and the worst of times".